# Integrating ASP.NET 5 with WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to use a simple Default.aspx WebForm generated from a simple ASP.NET application which uses WebForms. What I did is that I just copy and paste the entire Default.aspx and Default.aspx.cs.

When I tried to build the application, it fails. I'm not sure what's wrong.

[image: ASP.NET 5 project]

I'm curious about the DNX Core 5.0 which says the class it's not available there. What should I do? Anyways, here's my VS info:

[image]

Comment: The goal of ASP.NET 5 is to remove System.Web dependency, Use the latest version of ASP.NET 4.5 instead

Comment: I'm trying to assess the feasability of ASP.NET 5 promise of combining MVC, WebAPI and WebForms, which MS says is doable. I'm planning to "migrate" my site to incorporate these new technologies, using VS 2015. Is it wrong for me to try WebForms altogether in ASP.NET 5?

http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html

First sentence from the docs: ASP.NET 5 provides a host of improvements over its predecessors, including improved performance, better support for modern web development standards and tools, and improved integration between WebAPI, MVC, and WebForms.

Comment: ASP.NET 5 promise to combining MVC, WebAPI and [WebPage](http://www.asp.net/web-pages), not aspx WebForms.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, got the problem right here. It's the project.json definition.

[image: Project.json]

It seems I'm targeting multiple frameworks, just as Guruprasad said. Since I'm using WebForms, then I should use the full CLR instead of CoreCLR. Removing the "dnxcore50" did the trick.

Comment: Your title says "integrating asp.net 5" with webforms.  You aren't using asp.net 5.

Answer (score 1):

Check your solution! If your solution has multiple projects then try setting the `Target Framework` of all the projects to be the same and clean and rebuild.